# MySQL Workbench 8.0 data filling using foreign key

Tags: mysql

As you see in the picture below, I have some kind of information like this. The main information in `Regions_other` will be the following (in short):

```
NA      AMS
LATAM   AMS
APAC    APJ
```

As I will be using AMS/APJ format I created a `Regions` table to use them and `Regions other` as maybe I will need after these infos.

Question is the following, for example when I start to fill in `Regions_other` is there any mean to fill them using the info in `Regions`. For example, I am talking about `Data Validation` in Excel, when you say that in the cell there can be only the values from list X. As the table `Regions` is filled, wouldn't I be able to use them for filling the second table?

[image]

Comment: *As the table Regions is filled, wouldn't I be able to use them for filling the second table?* You can fill referenced field only (`Regions_Region_Name`, it seems) - insert those values from source table which not exists in destination table. You have no info for second field in source. But your `Regions_other_name` is defined as primary key - so you need to create unique fake value for each inserted record, and then update it to actual value.

Comment: @Akina thanks for response. The main part is about something similar to excel's data validation, for example, I wrote APAC, and when I want to fill Region_Name, is it possible to have list opened from where I can choose APJ?

Comment: *to have list opened?* SQL server have no any lists, and opens nothing. It is your client function. Nothing prevents after "I wrote APAC" to send a query to MySQL, obtain values referenced to 'APAC' value, fill your list with them and open it - but it is not database-related. And I do not know does Workbench have such feature. Read manual and/or test...